# Generate User provisioning report using API

Tags: oracle

We are trying to automate the provisioning report generation using some sort of API capability. We have Java7 installed on the linux server wehere we run scripts to perform other tasks on Oracle EPM (on premise)

[image: EPM]

We found an API sample with curl, but this applies only to the cloud:

```
curl -i -u "<username>:<password>" -X GET https://servername.fa.us2.oraclecloud.com/hcmRestApi/scim/Users
```

is there an API for onpremise that we can utilize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't allow login from script especially on in premises.

Comment: But you can try to export from DB.. For this you need to search for query. DB administrator can help you out. Run the provision report and from backend DB admin can provide you query that is running on DB